# Launching a new activity just by touching the screen

Tags: java, android

I am trying to launch a brand new activity that will display a new string when I touch the screen. Here is the MainActivity code. My first activity displays a "hello world", and my new activity should simply displays a new string. All the resource files and the manifest are correct. However, the run keeps crashing after the onClick.

```
package com.example.myfirsttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    
    //Call the NewActivity from the MainActivity
        View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,NewActivity.class);
                startActivity(startIntent);
                
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat of the crash please?

Comment: paste your logcat so we can see the error message

Comment: Have you registered the NewActivity on the Manifest?

Comment: 08-29 16:21:33.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1106):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)


08-29 16:21:33.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1106):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

08-29 16:21:33.732: E/AndroidRuntime(1106):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: These are the two registered activities:

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirsttest.NewActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category           android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: I just created a new project and copied your code into it. Without touching anything else in the project the click works. I am not sure what you mean by the new activity should display a new string. I still have the Hello World string in the text box and it gets displayed on both activities. Is there anything else that you might have changed? You should post anything that you have modified.

Comment: ok figured it out - I actually hadnt registered the second activity in the manifest. My second activity was pretty much the same as the first, except I used a different string... like "Hello Second world!". So the code posted above is actually correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way to accomplish this

```
package com.example.myfirsttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private static final String MESSAGE_TAG = "my_message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String stringMessage = extras.getString(MESSAGE_TAG);
    TextView message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    if(stringMessage != null && !stringMessage.isEmpty()) {
       message.setText(stringMessage);
    }


    //Call the NewActivity from the MainActivity
        View view = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startIntent.putExtra(MESSAGE_TAG, "hello second World");
                startActivity(startIntent);

            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Now you do not need to have 2 activities registered for the same task here is the layout

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```